# Modify the current URL string query with python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to modify an active URL in python. I'm able to modify the url of a hard-coded url within my existing code but I would like to modify the URL of the page on my apache server

For example if I'm on:

`http://localhost/?foo=stackoverflow`

I want my script to modify this to

`http://localhost/?foo=Hello stackoverflow`

A number of sources I've looked at regarding how to do this all have used hardcoded URLs. For reference here is my code on doing just that, with the modification I'm talking about.

```
 #!"C:/PythonPath"

import cgi
import datetime
import time

def htmlTop():
    print("""Content-type: text/html\n\n
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8"/>
            <title>My server template</title>
        </head>
        <body>""")
def htmlTail():
    print("""</body>
    </html>""")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        htmlTop()
        current_time = str(datetime.datetime.now())
        url = 'http://localhost/helloworld/?foo=bar'
        print(url)
        print("""<br></br>""")

        url_array = url.split('?')
        base_url = url_array[0] #'http://localhost/helloworld/?foo=bar'
        params = url_array[1] # query parameters 'foo'

        url_array2 = params.split("=") #['foo', 'bar']

        # print through all key values
        param_value_dict = {} # {'foo': 'bar'}
        for i, str in enumerate(url_array2):
            if i % 2 == 0:
                param_value_dict[str] = url_array2[i + 1]


        former_value = param_value_dict['foo'] # to store old value
        param_value_dict['foo'] = 'Hello '+former_value+'!  '+current_time

        # form the new url from the dictonary
        new_url = base_url + '?'
        for param_name, param_value in param_value_dict.items():
            new_url = new_url + param_name + "=" + param_value

        print(new_url.replace("%20", " "))
        htmlTail()
    except:
        cgi.print_exception()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are making this harder than it needs to be.

```
import datetime
url = 'http://localhost/helloworld/?foo=bar'
url += ' ' + str(datetime.datetime.now())
print url.replace('=', '=Hello ').replace(' ', '%20')
```

Result

```
http://localhost/helloworld/?foo=Hello%20bar%202018-08-22 03:53:41.775949
```

Comment: Again as I previously stated, this is assuming the url is hard-coded. This does not work on the active page `'http://localhost/helloworld/?foo=bar'`. I need the script to modify the currently active URL

Comment: No, it's not assuming the URL is hard coded... it's using the only example you gave. You can easily substitute the hard coded URL with `driver.current_url`. If you have others that we need to consider when creating an answer, then you should post several relevant URL examples that make this answer not work. This will work with any URL in the form <base url>?<parameters>=<text you want to put 'Hello' before>.